# In Ionic applications, from where the *cordova object* comes from?

Tags: cordova, ionic2

please put some light in this obscure path.

In Ionic applications we use a *cordova object* to access different things (ex.: cordova.file.foo, cordova.plugins, ...). Its access is made through the following declaration:

```
declare var cordova: any;
```

Where in the dark lies this *connection*? How this reference is made? If someone call tell the location where this occurs.

Comment: The right answer should point the file(s) where the magic occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova is a wrapper that enables access device native features through javascript. When you build with `ionic run Cordova`platform``. Cordova js injected with your build package. You have to install Cordova plugins separately.

If you use ionic latest. Then don't worry Cordova prepackaged. Just you have to ensure Cordova globally installed in your system. You may install `npm install -g cordova`.  Further for plugins https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/

If you use ionic 1.x  check this document for setup instruction.